# Cannot change li background on hover (in bootstrap navbar)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think Bootstrap is very hard to understand and override using CSS overriding rule (I don't really want to create my own custom Bootstrap CSS because really it's not very flexible, just one small change will require us to rebuild a new version of Bootstrap from the LESS source code).

What I want here is just simple that when hovering on a link (in a navbar), change its background to my own color, not the ***ugly*** default color Bootstrap sets. So even when I define an Id for my link element, CSS rule still does not work at all.

```css
li#li#li#li#li#li#li#li:hover {
   background-color:red!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="navbar" id="menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="li"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

As you can see even with that CSS rule, it cannot be overridden? Or I'm wrong with the actual element whose background is changed on hovering (while I think it should be actually the `li` element)?

Also I'm wondering if someone could explain to me by how Bootstrap could make that magic happen. I would like to apply that same magic in my own CSS plugin, it may be helpful in some case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's the `a` link element that's getting that background

```css
#li:hover a {
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="navbar" id="menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="li"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you. I'll accept as soon as possible.